# React Hooks: how to wait for the data to be fetched before rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have fetch method in useEffect hook:

```
export const CardDetails = () => {
  const [ card, getCardDetails ] = useState();

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/cards/${id}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => getCardDetails(data))
  }, [id])

  return (
     <DetailsRow data={card} />
  )
}
```

But then inside `DetailsRow` component this data is not defined, which means that I render this component before data is fetched. How to solve it properly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just don't render it when the data is `undefined`:

```
export const CardDetails = () => {
  const [card, setCard] = useState();

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/cards/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCard(data));
  }, [id]);

  if (card === undefined) {
    return <>Still loading...</>;
  }

  return <DetailsRow data={card} />;
};
```

Answer (score 17):

There are 3 ways to not render component if there aren't any data yet.

1. `{data && <Component data={data} />}`
2. Check `if(!data) { return null }` before render. This method will prevent **All** component render until there aren't any data.
3. Use some `<Loading />` component and ternar operator inside JSX. In this case you will be able to render all another parts of component which are not needed data -> `{data ? <Component data={data} /> : <Loading>}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const CardDetails = () => {
    const [card, setCard] = useState();
    const { id } = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!data) {
            fetch(`http://localhost:3001/cards/${id}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => setCard(data))
        }
    }, [id, data]);
    return (
        <div>
            {data && <DetailsRow data={card} />}
            {!data && <p>loading...</p>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display some default data for user instead of a loading spinner while waiting for server data. Here is a code of a react hook which can fetch data before redering.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

var receivedData: any = null

type Listener = (state: boolean, data: any) => void
export type Fetcher = () => Promise<any>
type TopFetch = [
    loadingStatus: boolean,
    data: any,
]
type AddListener = (cb: Listener) => number
type RemoveListener = (id: number) => void
interface ReturnFromTopFetch {
    addListener: AddListener,
    removeListener: RemoveListener
}
type StartTopFetch = (fetcher: Fetcher) => ReturnFromTopFetch

export const startTopFetch = function (fetcher: Fetcher) {
    let receivedData: any = null
    let listener: Listener[] = []
    function addListener(cb: Listener): number {
        if (receivedData) {
            cb(false, receivedData)
            return 0
        }
        else {
            listener.push(cb)
            console.log("listenre:", listener)
            return listener.length - 1
        }
    }
    function removeListener(id: number) {

        console.log("before remove listener: ", id)
        if (id && id >= 0 && id < listener.length) {
            listener.splice(id, 1)
        }
    }
    let res = fetcher()
    if (typeof res.then === "undefined") {
        receivedData = res
    }
    else {
        fetcher().then(
            (data: any) => {
                receivedData = data
            },
        ).finally(() => {
            listener.forEach((cb) => cb(false, receivedData))
        })

    }
    return { addListener, removeListener }
} as StartTopFetch

export const useTopFetch = (listener: ReturnFromTopFetch): TopFetch => {

    const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        const id = listener.addListener((v: boolean, data: any) => {
            setLoadingStatus(v)
            receivedData = data
        })
        console.log("add listener")
        return () => listener.removeListener(id)
    }, [listener])
    return [loadingStatus, receivedData]

}
```

This is what myself needed and couldn't find some simple library so I took some time to code one. it works great and here is a demo:

```
import { startTopFetch, useTopFetch } from "./topFetch";

// a fakeFetch 
const fakeFetch = async () => {
    const p = new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ value: "Data from the server" })
        }, 1000)
    })
    return p
}

//Usage: call startTopFetch before your component function and pass a callback function, callback function type: ()=>Promise<any>
const myTopFetch = startTopFetch(fakeFetch)

export const Demo = () => {
    const defaultData = { value: "Default Data" }
    
    //In your component , call useTopFetch and pass the return value from startTopFetch.    
    const [isloading, dataFromServer] = useTopFetch(myTopFetch)
    return <>
        {isloading ? (
        <div>{defaultData.value}</div>
        ) : (
        <div>{dataFromServer.value}</div>
        )}
    </>
}
```