# React State updates too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I try to render a list with products but unfortunely the list updates too late.
The Products List is empty. When I execute it the second time it works.
Is there any solution?

Thank you very much!

```
export const Products = (props) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [ListProducts, setListProducts] = useState([]);
    const [List, setList] = useState([]);

    const loadProducts = async (categorieid) => {
        const apiProducts = await axios.get(`${url}/products/${categorieid}`);
        setProducts(apiProducts.data.body);
    };

    const mapData = async () => {
        if (products && products.length) {
            products.map((product) =>
                ListProducts.push(
                    <ProductCard product={product} key={product.id} />
                )
            );
            setListProducts(ListProducts);
        } else {
            List.push(
                <div className="column">
                    <span className="title has-text-grey-light">
                        No products found!
                    </span>
                </div>
            );
        }
    const renderListProducts = () => {
        return <div className="container">{ListProducts}</div>;
    };

    const writeCategory = async (kategorieId) => {
        await loadProducts(kategorieId);
        await mapData();
        await renderListProducts();
    };
}
```

Comment: Wait until `loadProducts` finishes before trying to render

Comment: I call mapData after loadProducts but that doesn’t work correctly

Comment: That's basically how it's supposed to work. When the component renders with initial state, it's empty. State is set and component re-renders with the data.

Comment: It also looks like you're setting some state with the rendered items, which isn't how render should be done. The state has the raw data and render creates the `ProductCard` each time it is called.

Comment: I added more code

Comment: Does this would answer your question? [React Hooks: how to wait for the data to be fetched before rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63281536/1218980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is in here

```
 const writeCategory = async (kategorieId) => {
        await loadProducts(kategorieId);
        await mapData();
        await renderListProducts();
    };
```

`setProducts` is called at the end of `loadProducts`, but it is not necessary will update the state before `mapData` will be called.
The solution is to use `useEffect` as the trigger for next function

```
const writeCategory = async (kategorieId) => {
        loadProducts(kategorieId);      
    };

useEffect(() => { products.length && mapData(), [products.length] }
```

and so on for the third function `renderListProducts`

BTW in

```
products.map((product) =>
                ListProducts.push(
                    <ProductCard product={product} key={product.id} />
                )
            )
```

you're modifying `ListProducts` state outside `setState`, consider do something like

```
const temp = products.map((product) => <ProductCard product={product} key={product.id} /> )
setListProducts(temp)
```

instead