# Call an async function with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call an async function but I am getting an error

> getUsersList(db).then is not a function

this is my code

```
async function getUsersList(db) {
  const userCol = collection(db, 'Users');
  const userSnapshot = await getDocs(userCol);
  const tempUserList = userSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return tempUserList;
}


function App() {

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const auth = getAuth(app);


  var currentUser = auth.currentUser;

  if(currentUser != null){
    getUsersList(db).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);

});
```

I also tried using await getUsersList but got the following error

> Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: you can't use await unless you're in an async function, and since I guess that App() is a react component, you wont be able to call it like this.

Comment: Maybe have a look at react-async and usefetch(). Or don't use await if you can.

Comment: such error response usually means that the function you have called `.then` upon isn't a promise. Have you checked the type returned by the `getUserList` function?

Comment: Are you sure sure that the `getUsersList` function you show us is representative of the one in your code? Because the function you show is fine and it would be impossible for it to **not** return a Promise.

Comment: We should see the code of getDocs function in order to trace the problem

Comment: @Normal `getDocs` doesn't matter. worst case it throws, then `getUsersList` would return  a rejected Promise. But as stated, with the current code it's impossible for `getUsersList` to not return a Promise, rejected, resolved, containing whatever value, but definitely a Promise.

Comment: `getUsersList.then`,   I don't see any code that says that, please provide the actual code that generates the error.

Comment: This is exactly the code I am using. I copied the function from https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: That says `getUsersList(db).then`...

Answer (score 0):

So what I assume you're trying to do here `const userSnapshot = await getDocs(userCol);` is fetch some data that is then going to be used in your react component to render something (Maybe there's a fetch request in getDocs ?)

1. There is no return in your react component (but that's not what's causing your issue).
2. As it is it won't work using await since App() isn't an async function BUT you can't make it an async function since this is a standard react component.
3. What do you want to happen whilst waiting for the data to be fetched (= whilst your promise is pending) ? If you're happy to display nothing, why not just remove await before getDocs() ?

For more on this topic :

[React: async and await not working with fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507362/react-async-and-await-not-working-with-fetch)

[React Hooks: how to wait for the data to be fetched before rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281536/react-hooks-how-to-wait-for-the-data-to-be-fetched-before-rendering)